# Change text on click and keep changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, onclick

I have  div with "Hey". That changes to "Are you ok?" when i click on it. But I want to contiue having more texts. How can I make it so that when I click the "Are you ok" another text appears, and so on...

HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#fold").click(function () {
      $("#fold_p").text("Are you ok?");
    } )
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><div id="fold">
     <p id="fold_p">Hey</p>
</div>
```

Also, is it possible to make the last text a link? Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: You could hold the text in an array and loop through that on each click... **Example** https://jsfiddle.net/b0vjgny9/

Comment: Create an array of messages. Each time you click, put the next message in the array into the text.

Comment: do you want it to loop infinitely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve both functionality in `jQuery` as well as in `JavaScript`.

- Dynamic text change on click of previous displayed text.
- last text as a link

**Using JavaScript**

```js
var text = ["First","Second","Third","Fourth"]

var index = 0;
document.getElementById("fold").onclick = function() {
  index++;
  if(index < text.length) {
    if(index == text.length-1) {
    document.getElementById("fold_p").innerHTML = '<a href="">'+text[index]+'</a>';
    } else {
    document.getElementById("fold_p").innerHTML = text[index];
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="fold">
     <p id="fold_p">Hey</p>
</div>
```

**Using jQuery**

```js
var text = ["First","Second","Third","Fourth"]

var index = 0;
$("#fold").click(function () {
  index++;
  if(index < text.length) {
  if(index == text.length-1) {
    $("#fold_p").html('<a href="">'+text[index]+'</a>');
  } else {
    $("#fold_p").text(text[index]);
  }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="fold">
     <p id="fold_p">Hey</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you really helped me. But I'm still confused about the last word as a link.

Sorry I'm pretty new to html and friends and I'm using it for a work

Comment: You asked in your question how to make last text as a link. So I answered that part as well.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just still don't get how it works. How do imake it go to an external page.

Comment: You can provide any `link` inside href here `<a href="">'+text[index]+'</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Here you go! Simply **create an array** like described in the comments!

```js
var text = ["Hi","One","Two","Three","Four"]

$(document).ready(function () {
    var index = 0;
    $("#fold").click(function () {
      index++;
      $("#fold_p").text(text[index]);
    } )
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><div id="fold">
     <p id="fold_p">Hey</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. I'm gonna try it

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an array and then shift the array in order to have different blurbs to spit out.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  textList = ["Are you okay?", "Well that's cool.", "I like puppies"];
  $("#fold").click(function () {
    $("#fold_p").text(textList.shift());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><div id="fold">
     <p id="fold_p">Hey</p>
</div>
```